# Adding an input field to primary key in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, primary-key

I'm new to CakePHP and still really have  no thorough understanding. if I have a mysql database with only a primary key field how can I make an input field for it using cake bake option.
After baking I tried adding this line to the view file generated

```
<fieldset>
<legend><?php echo __('Add Id'); ?></legend>
<?php
        **echo $this->Form->input('identity');**
?>
</fieldset>
```

It did not work ...
What is the correct method to get an input field for the primary key?

The table id has only one field named identity in the data base

Comment: The table id has only one field named identity in the data base

Comment: do you want to say that textbox is not getting displayed ... ?

Comment: yes I can not get the input text box to appear

Comment: have you created the form first .. ?

Comment: <div class="ids form">
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Id'); ?>
 <fieldset>
  <legend><?php echo __('Edit Id'); ?></legend>
 <?php
  echo $this->Form->input('identity');
 ?>
 </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
</div> 
is this what you asked? I just started using cakephp

Comment: $this->Form->create('Id'); this is wrong check this link http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html

Comment: This kind of input field and form creation works for non primary key fields, I used the bake function to create the MCV. It created the form above. What do i have to change to make it right? I read the documentation but could not grasp the idea well.

Comment: It has nothing to do with primary or non primary fields .. I have a table with empno as primary key .. and i write this code in my view file   <?php
echo $this->Form->create();
echo $this->Form->input('empno');

?> and it works like charm ... problem lies somewhere else

Comment: can I see your view file? I checked the generated html page source. There I can see the form is created as said in the document but the input I create is made into type hidden.

Comment: I have just written the two lines that I sent you in previous comment.. ..I had creatd it for testing only

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11684596/cakephp-2-0-this-form-input

this is just what I'm facing now. But with my table I can not make it auto increment. 
The solution there is not working for me.

Comment: now I am even more confused .. because empno in my case is not auto-incriment ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CakePHP will, by default, output primary key fields as a hidden input. You can override it by specifying the 'type' of input to use, e.g.:

```
echo $this->Form->input('identity', array('type' => 'text'));
```

However, CakePHP supports two type of Primary Keys; autoNumber integers and GUID/UUID primary keys. Manually setting primary keys (e.g. use 'username' as primary key and trying to **insert** or **edit** the username) may cause problems, because CakePHP assumes that an *update* should be performed if the primary is not empty in your form.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#model-and-database-conventions

Answer (score 1):

Change your statement to this:

```
echo $this->Form->input('id', array ('type'=>'text'));
```

You should now have the id in full view.

CakePHP used the `id` or index, to determine, if the form entry is a new entry (ie INSERT) or an update to the existing extry (ie UPDATE).

If you make the index editable,  you will have to deal with this issue, else you can end up having multiple records, one with the original record and a second record with the changes.